# IIS web.config redirect rule for specific URL but not others

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I want to add a redirect rule to the web.config file http://myurl.com/path/to/old
to http://myurl.com/path/to/new

but http://myurl.com/fr/path/to/old

http://myurl.com/cn/path/to/old

should stay the same. how can i achieve that with match/rule?

Comment: Use asp.net mvc Route attribute.

Comment: Check this page https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your web.config:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect old to new" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^path/to/old" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^fr/.*" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^cn/.*" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/path/to/new" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```